# Given that set $X=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ and $A=\{a,c,d\}$. List the $A$- inclusion topology on X.

Tags: general-topology

The question comes on the basis of general topology. Am trying to get deep into the terms and applications required.

Comment: Please use Latex

Comment: define the $A$-inclusion topology?

Answer (score 0):

If this topology is what I'm guessing it to be, it will be

$$\{\emptyset, X, A=\{a,c,d\}, \{a,b,c,d\}, \{a,c,d,e\}\}$$

We need the supersets of $A$ in $X$, so we add nothing, $b$ or $e$ or both of them to $A$ and that's all we have.